# How to write a SQL script to read contents of a file

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, xlsx

I have a SQL script and a ".csv" file. I want the SQL script to read the data from the ".csv" file instead of manually entering the data in the script. Is it possible?

```
....
.....
......
and SP_F.trade_id = SP_R.trade_id 
and SP_R.iSINCode IN (here is where I can manually enter the data)
```

ps: I am new to SQL and I am still learning.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s : Sorry, I added the tag now. Its oracle.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/) is good solution.

```
BULK INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.csv'
WITH
(
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

More explained:

1) We have csv file named *test.csv* with such content:

```
'JE000DT', 'BE000DT2J', 'DE000DT2'
1, 2, 3
2, 3, 4
4, 5, 6
```

2) We need to create table for this file in DB:

```
CREATE TABLE CSVTest ([columnOne] int, [columnTwo] int, [columnThree] int)
```

3) Insert your data with BULK INSERT. The columns count and type must match your csv.

```
BULK INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'C:\test.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    FIRSTROW = 2
)
```

4) Use your this table in yours subquery:

```
Select
    SP_F.trade_id, -- as 'Trade ID',
    SP_F.issuer_id, --as 'Issuer ID',
    SP_R.iSINCode --as 'ISIN'
from t_SP_Fundamentals SP_F
    JOIN t_SP_References SP_R ON SP_F.trade_id = SP_R.trade_id
where 
    (SP_F.issuer_id = 3608 or SP_F.issuer_id = 3607)
    and SP_R.iSINCode IN (SELECT [columnOne] FROM CSVTest)
```

There is another solution with *OPENROWSET* statement, that allows direct reading from the file. But I strongly recommend you to use the solution above. Reading direct from the file in QUERY is not very great choose.

Comment: Can you please tell me where to add your script in the following script?

Select 
SP_F.trade_id, -- as 'Trade ID',
SP_F.issuer_id, --as 'Issuer ID',
SP_R.iSINCode --as 'ISIN'

from 
t_SP_Fundamentals SP_F
, t_SP_References SP_R
where (SP_F.issuer_id = 3608 or SP_F.issuer_id = 3607) 
and SP_F.trade_id = SP_R.trade_id 
and SP_R.iSINCode IN (here is where the data from the .csv file should be read)

Comment: Can you add an example of your csv file?

Comment: Just a single column with a header in the first cell and about 4000 rows.


Header
'JE000DT',
'BE000DT2J',
'DE000DT2',
'DE000DT21',
'JE000DT23',
'BE000DT2J21',
'JE000DT2U8',
.
.
.
.

Comment: If it realy helped you, mark this post as "Answer". Thanks.